# format date (from mongodb) in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, momentjs

Each blog post has a date in my mongodb database.

I want to get the date from the database and format it in the list route (posts controller) below.
How would I do this?

Note: I have tried using moment.js however I don't know how to get the date from the database.

date in Post model

```
 date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
    }
)

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema)
```

posts controller

```
const Post = require("../models/Post");

const {
  errorHandler
} = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler");

exports.list = (req, res) => {
    Post.find({}, function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.send(err);
      } else {
        res.send(result);
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: You should have the `date` field in the `result`. `console.log` to check it. Then format it then way u want before sending back with `res.send(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Can  you try to add 'date' property after empty object, this will select date records from db.

```
const Post = require("../models/Post");

const {
   errorHandler
} = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler");

exports.list = (req, res) => {
   Post.find({},'date', function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
};
```